# Question about how to represent data in perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I'm messing around in perl, and I want to build a script to print hockey points and assists, with the date. It's about 40 rows, and I want to associate the date with the 2 pieces of information. I'm stuck on how to implement this.

Something
Like
10/24 2 goals 1 assist

As well filtering the totals. I can do this in a simple DB and use SQL but that seems like an overblown solution. (Plus I want to learn more perl). I feel I may be overthinking this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does your data input look like?

Answer (score 3):

When you represent structured data in Perl (and many other languages), it's common to use a hashmap. Perl doesn't have structs, so developers typically use hashes with well-known keys (which is also what many object-oriented frameworks in Perl end up doing under the hood). Without knowing anything else about your other goals, I'd start with something like this:

```perl
my %data = (
  "2022-11-24" => { goals => 2, assists => 1 },
  "2022-11-23" => { goals => 3, assists => 0 },
  ...
);
```

From this data structure, you can:

```perl
# get today's number of assists
my $assists_today = $data{"2022-11-24"}{assists};
# sum up each day's number of goals
my $total_goals = 0;
$total_goals += $data{$_}{goals} foreach keys %data;
```

Comment: `$total_goals += $_->{goals} for values %data;`

Comment: `my $total_goals = sum 0, map { $_->{goals} } values %data;` (with List::Util's `sum`) allows you to skip `my $total_goals = 0;`.